# Azure Tables: best practices for choosing partition/row keys

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

What would be best practices for choosing partition/row keys for entities in Azure Tables? The common advice is to magically balance between partition size and number of partitions. But no one seems to have a good definition of how it can be accomplished in 3 easy steps. Is there a general approach for choosing keys so that everything then just works?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is a detailed article on this very subject up on MSDN: [Designing a scalable partitioning strategy for Windows Azure Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh508997.aspx).

Comment: Is there a default or implicit partition key if you do not set one? I cannot find this information anywhere. I'm kind of assuming it's `id` right now.

Comment: As with any answer on SO, please provide actual information and not just a link.

Answer (score 10):

I've just recently been looking into the exact same thing and found this good quality article that covers Partition Keys, Row Keys and lots more: [Azure Storage Table Design Guide: Designing Scalable and Performant Tables](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/)

Comment: For the record, the link here is now much better and more recent than the accepted answer.